# Stress of הושיעה and הצליחה in Hallel

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk, pronunciation, tehilim-psalms, hallel

Why is הושיעה [Mileel](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1338/759) (penultimately [stressed](http://wals.info/chapter/14)) whereas הצליחה is [Milra](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1338/759) (ultimately stressed) in [Psalms 118:25](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%97_%D7%9B%D7%94)?

Comment: Another question about the same verse: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47553

Comment: In your links both are written Milra.

Comment: Oh, I see I added that link some time back. In any event, please source your assumption (that one is Milra and one is Mileil).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71276

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, it's due to a misinterpretation of the *m'sora*. By the rules of grammar, both should be *mil'el*, but, according to the *m'sora*, both are *mil'ra*. The *m'sora* was misinterpreted to mean that *hoshia* is *mil'el* while *hatzlicha* is *mil'ra*, and that's the way people read it now. Source: [an old `mesorah`-listserv thread on the topic](http://lists.aishdas.org/pipermail/mesorah-aishdas.org/2008-July/thread.html#371), in particular [one message from that thread](http://lists.aishdas.org/pipermail/mesorah-aishdas.org/2008-July/000372.html), quoting [Rabbi *Mord'chay* Breuer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Breuer).

As to *why* the *m'sora* specifies an ungrammatical reading on this *pasuk*, I don't know, but such a circumstance is not uncommon.

---

EDIT: See this picture of the verse as written in the [Aleppo Codex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleppo_codex) which indicates the *mil'ra* emphasis on each of the two words. (Note also the *dagesh* in both instances of the word *na*, which is also discussed in the listserv message linked to above.)
[image: (image of Aleppo Codex)]

Answer (score 2):

I've heard once that "Hatzl**i**ha na" means "you have success" and "Hatzlih**a** na" means "make us to have success".