# What type of Dagesh is נָּא֙ from (Breishis 38:16)

Tags: grammar-dikduk, torah-reading

On the pasuk of "הָ֤בָה נָּא֙ אָב֣וֹא אֵלַ֔יִךְ" there is a dagesh in front of a word on a the letter nun.  What type of Dagesh is this?  Shouldn't there not be a dagesh chazak on front of a word?

Comment: http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c26b8.htm#25 ?

Comment: Look up the terms דחיק and אתי מרחק. These degeshim show up every few verses

Comment: The leining this morning has לְכָה-נָּא אָרָה-לִּי נַכֶּה-בּוֹ קָבָה-לִּי

Comment: @DoubleAA those four are one word each. The one in the question is not. (I'm basing my statement on the way y'all wrote it: I haven't checked.)

Comment: @msh in this week's parsha is also אָשׁוּבָה לִּי and next week we have וְהָיְתָה לּוֹ

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer is that this type of dagesh is a Deḥiq (דחיק 'compressed')
The reason for the dagesh in נא is because of a phenomenon known as deḥiq (aka, apparently, ate meraḥiq). Deḥiq is the name for when a word receives an initial dagesh when:

1) The word before the word getting the deḥiq end in a vowel.

2) The stress on the word preceding that with the deḥiq is penultimate (milʿel)

3) The stress on the word preceding that with the deḥiq is marked by a conjunctive accent (or a maqef merges the words).

4) The stress on the word receiving the deḥiq is on the initial syllable (or one after a shewa naʿ). More rarely, the stress on the word getting the deḥiq is not initial, but an initial secondary stress is present (marked by a gaʿya), e.g. וְעָשִׂ֤יתָ סִּֽירֹתָיו֙ (Shemot 27:3).

See below for more information.

[Dagesh on Hatslicha nna](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71276/dagesh-on-hatslicha-nna)